# activated python venv but installs globally

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, python-venv

```
pip3 list | grep unicorn
```

returns no results

```
source ~/scripts/venv/unicorn-hat-sim/bin/activate
```

prompt changes to show venv is activated

```
pip3 install unicorn-hat-sim
pip3 list | grep unicorn
unicorn-hat-sim   1.0.0
pip3 show unicorn-hat-sim
Name: unicorn-hat-sim
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Unicorn HAT (HD) simulator - Originally by Jannis Hermanns <jannis@gmail.com>
Home-page: https://github.com/mapitman/unicorn-hat-sim
Author: Mark Pitman
Author-email: mark.pitman@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/rossgoodmancom/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: pygame
Required-by:
```

As you can see it has been installed in the .local/lib rather than in the venv
I confirmed this by

```
deactivate
pip3 list | grep unicorn
unicorn-hat-sim   1.0.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Verify that the `pip3` you're running is actually coming from your virtual environment (e.g., make sure `which pip3` returns `~/scripts/venv/unicorn-hat-sim/bin/pip3`.

Comment: which pip3 returned /usr/bin/pip3

Comment: I took the nuclear approach and deleted all of my virtual environment folders.
Created again using pip3 -m venv folder_name and it seems to be working correctly now ....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I did wrong but deleting the venv folders and re-creating did the job.